# Почему он требует аргумент с содержанием если я указал группу

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

```
import argparse

args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args.add_argument('-u','--url',help='',metavar='')

group = args.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-s','--scan',help='scan url',metavar='URL')

args = args.parse_args()

def main():
    if args.scan:
        print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ошибка `error: argument -s/--scan: expected one argument`

Comment: а вы указали значение параметра "-s / --scan"? С какими аргументами вы запускали скрипт?

Comment: @MaxU Ну естественно

Comment: @MaxU В этом то и дело он не должен принимать не каких значений параметра,я должен ввести флаг `-s`  и программа должна вывести `hello`

Comment: если не указывать группу, то результат здесь абсолютно такой же: по умолчанию argparse аргумент требует значение. [argparse module How to add option without any argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5262702/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `action="store_true"`:

```
group.add_argument('-s','--scan',help='scan url',action="store_true")
```

Пример запуска:

```
C:\Temp>python "arg.py" -s
hello
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное